# jquery mobile dialog call to diallog though a link not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, dialog

I have this document with two simple pages defined:

```
 //page1
         ...
         <a href="#dialog" id="link_open_dialog" data-rel="dialog">Click me</a>
         ...

 //page2
    <div data-role="page" id="dialog">           
         <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Something</h1>
          </div>
          <div data-role="content" id="textDialog">
              something
          </div>  
     </div>
```

But the problem is that I cannot see the dialog, never.........is the most simple case I think

Comment: Hi! Did you load the jQuery Mobile references correctly? Have you checked your console?

Comment: This is the head of my document with the different pages, in that I load all the js, and css
https://gist.github.com/3824261

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not define jQuery Mobile's references correctly, or you may check your console for errors.

Try the following working example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- PAGE 1 -->
        <div id="page_1" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="content">
                <a href="#dialog" id="link_open_dialog" data-rel="dialog">Click me</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- PAGE 2: DIALOG -->
        <div data-role="page" id="dialog">           
            <div data-role="header">
                <h1>Something</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content" id="textDialog">
                something
            </div>  
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that work!, jum...., now I can start to think that Im not crazy. Thank you!, I'll try to discover what happen, this has the same structrure of my template. Thank you!

Comment: I'll write when I figure out something

Comment: @MrQ.C. : the example I provided does work ! You may give more details to your problem (ex: any console error maybe ?)...

Answer (score 0):

the problem was a parameter from the template. Nothing in relation with jquery Mobile. the parameter was an empty chain (""), but I didnt know that because that part exactly was not complete, so was hard to test it. THank you a lot, I spent hours with this simple problem

Answer (score -2):

Not familiar with this plugin, but looks like you need to specify `data role` as `"button"`, otherwise no event is fired... just a guess.

```
<a data-role="button" data-rel="dialog">hello</a>

    <div data-role="dialog">Hello World</div>
```